# Net6 GetDirectories missing folder

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I'm running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTSx64 and using

```
dotnet --version
6.0.109
```

I'm trying to list the directories in /usr (ultimately I'm trying to open a file nested deeper within but this is where the problem is right now) and for some reason `Directory.GetDirectories("/usr")` is not returning all the folders in /usr specifically the local folder is left out for some reason

[image: Directory Listing]

[image: Dotnet Files Listing]

While attempting to do the same operation via python works fine.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('/usr')
['share', 'local', 'lib32', 'lib64', 'include', 'bin', 'src', 'games', 'libx32', 'sbin', 'libexec', 'lib']
>>>
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Folders are returned correctly for you. Looks like your dotnet app returned content of the "/usr/local", not the "/usr". Can you share more details, how you run the app? From what location? For me it works as expected

Comment: Definitely, I use Jetbrains Rider so most of the time i'm executing it from there, the working directory is "/home/chewy/RiderProjects/PasswordGenerator/PasswordGenerator/bin/Debug/net6.0" and running with just dotnet run gives the same results

Comment: I don't think it is returning the content of "/usr/local" either, it's returning 11 directories and my "usr/local" only has 9, it doesn't match up with the ls output of "/usr" either though

Comment: My rider is installed as a flatpak would that have any affect on what it thinks the /usr directory is while running?